# Http Post returns two set of arrays, how to store these array in two different observable in angular

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array

I am doing a http post from angular and my api sends me two set of arrays in return, now i want to store these arrays separately in two different observable array, how do I achieve this in angular.

Comment: can you add more detail and code ? possible stackblitz. API is itself a obserable in angular if you are using http client do you want to break in parts ? How you want to use it. Http observable is single dimension ? you want to use as multi dimension ?

Answer (score 0):

Using forkJoin in RxJs you can combine results from multiple api calls into single request and then split off into different observables when returned. If you have one single response, you just need to split the arrays on a common key.

Here's forkJoin

```
async BuildForkJoinRepriceUI(){
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject)=> {
  const Type1 = this.http.post(this.ApiUrl + "url/1/get", {});
  const Type2 = this.http.post(this.ApiUrl + "url/2/get", {});
  const Type3 = this.http.post(this.ApiUrl + "url/3/get", {});
  const Type4 = this.http.post(this.ApiUrl + "url/4/get", {}); 
  const Type5 = this.http.post(this.ApiUrl + "url/5/get", {}); 
  const Type6 = this.http.post(this.ApiUrl + "url/6/get", {}); 
  const Type7 = this.http.post(this.ApiUrl + "url/7/get", {}); 
  forkJoin([Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4, Type5, Type6, Type7])
  .subscribe((response:any) => {
    let statusCheck = response.filter(status => (status.StatusCode != "Success"));
    if(statusCheck.length){
      reject(false);
    } 
    Type1Observable.next(response[0].Data);
    Type2Observable.next(response[1].Data);
    Type3Observable.next(response[2].Data);
    Type4Observable.next(response[3].Data);
    Type5Observable.next(response[4].Data);
    Type6Observable.next(response[5].Data);
    Type7Observable.next(response[6].Data);
    resolve(true);
  })
})
}
```